# Android - Cannot resize AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I am trying to resize an AlertDialog, which I have done before, but cannot remember how I did it. Below is the code Ive used, but it just inst working. Is anyone able to point out what I am doing wrong.

```
   AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setMessage(R.string.checkout_journey_selector_popup_title)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.checkout_journey_selector_popup_paylater_button,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            CheckoutHelper.startReservationJourney(getActivity(),
                                    collectibleItems);
                        }
                    })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.checkout_journey_selector_popup_paynow_button,
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            CheckoutHelper.startPrepayCollectionJourney(getActivity(),
                                    collectibleItems);
                        }
                    }).create().show();



    Dialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    lp.copyFrom(alert.getWindow().getAttributes());

    lp.height = 100; 
    lp.width = 50;
    alert.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: try this `alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400);` after `alertDialog.show();`

Comment: create custom alert dialog in layout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should replace this

```
Dialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
lp.copyFrom(alert.getWindow().getAttributes());
lp.height = 100; 
lp.width = 50;
alert.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

With

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
lp.copyFrom(alertDialogBuilder.getWindow().getAttributes());
lp.height = 100; 
lp.width = 50;
alertDialogBuilder.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
```

Or try this

```
alertDialog.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400); after alertDialog.show();
```

Try first and give me feedback

Comment: so I replaced it with:
        Dialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
        lp.copyFrom(alert.getWindow().getAttributes());
        lp.height = 300; 
        lp.width = 300;
        alert.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);
        alert.show();

But sadly it just displays in the standard size

Comment: @AndrewMurphy yes first try this one

Comment: I cant use:

lp.copyFrom(alertDialogBuilder.getWindow().getAttributes());

because getWindow is not applicable to AlertDialog

Comment: @AndrewMurphy why not? first you plz try this

Comment: i added the following and it worked:

        AlertDialog alert = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alert.show();
        alert.getWindow().setLayout(600, 400);

Comment: @AndrewMurphy that's what i m talk in about.

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
alert.getWindow().setLayout(width, height);

//then show it
alert.show();
```

instead of `alert.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);`